# How to change the color of the title page of a template in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: libreoffice, presentation

I am using the midnightblue template in LibreIffice Impress.

While I like the slides in this template, I want to change the background color of the elements in the title page. How to do that?

[image]
 <sup>I like the style of the slides but I want to change the title page</sup>

I am using Libreoffice 7.1 from the LibreOffice Fresh PPA, in Xubuntu 20.04.

**Clarification**: I want to change the background color of the title page (cyan and dark blue in this particular template), **not** the font color (which can be easily changed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember terminology correctly, then you need to edit properties of Master Slide, maybe its styles.

See for example the following chapter of LibreOffice Impress Guide - [Chapter 2 Master Slides, Styles, and Templates](https://documentation.libreoffice.org/assets/Uploads/Documentation/en/IG70/IG70-ImpressGuide.pdf) .

From the PDF guide,

1. Open `View` → `Master Slide`.
2. Right click on the desired region, and click on `Edit Style...`.
3. `Area` → `Color`, and you can choose your favorite color/gradient.

Comment: I want to modify the background color of the title page, not the font color. The font color can be modified in a much simpler way (select and change its color in the home tab).